# getting first row of data from multiple rows with same id codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

Been searching for answers to my query error in Codeigniter: I want to get the first row in multiple rows with same id from database. unfortunately, this error always comes up.

```
Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'blitzwor_g3d.orders.total_price' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

This is the query from my model:

```
 public function all()
  {    
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->filters($this->table);
    $this->db->group_by('order_id');
    $res = $this->db->get($this->table)->result();
    return $this->formatData($res);
  }
```

I've also tried using $this->db->distinct() but it does no effect.

Some blogs recommend to change the sql mode but I can't do that because there are other websites connected to the database and can affect their behavior.

any way to achieve this?

Comment: There must be a reason you're doing the group by, but that something (a SUM or MAX or MIN or ...) is not visible in your question. What's that something? It's almost never `SELECT *` is the data one needs.

Comment: I am trying to select the first row from each multiple rows with identical id. I've tried it when selecting single column order_id and it works well, but I wanna get all columns associated with that order_id so I use select('*') but neither works. is ther any orkaround on this?

Comment: If there are multiple rows for the same `order_id`, they are surely different. Aren't you interested in those differences? If not, it might happen that your database design is not the best. Strictly answering your question, there's the `ANY_VALUE` function you might want to check out - you have to list in the select statement all the fields you want but don't have in the order_by; something like `$this->db->select('order_id, ANY_VALUE(fieldA) AS fieldA, ANY_VALUE(fieldB) AS fieldB', ...)`

Comment: @ZoliSzabó, You just saved my life! any_value fits perfectly for distinct function. I am using multiple order_id to group orders taken at the same time by the customer. thanks to you!